# Error messages when implementing cross validation with logistic regression in R

Tags: r, for-loop, logistic-regression, cross-validation, r-caret

I am new to R and trying to run a logistic regression with five fold cross validation in R on the following data set for predictive purposes:

```
> str(data_known)
'data.frame':   91708 obs. of  16 variables:
$ order_item_id     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 12 ...
$ order_date        : Factor w/ 12 levels "2012-04","2012-05",..: 6 8 
10 5 6 12 10 3 10 12 ...
$ item_id           : int  1507 1745 2588 164 1640 2378 1506 224 2640 
2624 ...
$ item_size         : Factor w/ 99 levels "1","10","10+",..: 95 2 98 53
92 47 95 53 95 53 ...
$ brand_id          : int  102 64 42 47 97 72 102 58 41 12 ...
$ item_price        : num  24.9 75 79.9 79.9 69.9 ...
$ user_id           : int  46943 60979 72232 41242 8810 15761 64795
23489 69092 23261 ...
$ user_title        : Factor w/ 5 levels "Company","Family",..: 4 4 4 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ user_dob          : Factor w/ 607 levels "1943-01","1943-02",..: 263
368 80 216 342 274 NA 264 274 246 ...
$ user_state        : Factor w/ 16 levels "Baden-Wuerttemberg",..: 11 4
12 16 1 10 13 10 13 2 ...
$ user_reg_date     : Factor w/ 26 levels "2011-02","2011-03",..: 1 4
24 19 12 1 23 1 24 1 ...
$ delivery_time_days: Factor w/ 18 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 3 5 3 6 4 
12 5 5 11 4 ...
$ user_title_NA     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ item_size_NA      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ user_dob_NA       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
$ target            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Return","No Return": 1 2 1 1
1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
```

For the regression I first tried using the caret solution:

```
train_control<-trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
model.lr.cv<-train(formula = data_known$target ~., data = data_known,   
trControl = train_control, method = "glm", family = binomial(link = 
"logit"))
```

And receive the error message:

```
"Error in na.fail.default(list(order_item_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L,  : missing values in object"
```

I then tried to circumvent the problem by running glm by means of a for loop instead, reading:

```
explanatory_variables.lr.cv<-names(data_known)[-c(16)]
form.lr.cv<-as.formula(paste("target ~", 
paste(explanatory_variables.lr.cv, collapse = "+")))  
folds.lr.cv<-split(data_known,cut(sample(1:nrow(data_known)),5))
list_models.lr.cv<-list()
list_raw_pred.lr.cv<-list()

for (i in 1:length(folds.lr.cv)) {
test.lr.cv<-ldply(folds.lr.cv[i],data.frame)
train.lr.cv<-ldply(folds.lr.cv[-i],data.frame)
tmp.model.lr.cv<-glm(form.lr.cv, data = train.lr.cv, family =   
binomial(link = "logit"))
list_models.lr.cv[[i]]<-tmp.model.lr.cv
tmp.predict.lr.cv<-predict(tmp.model.lr.cv, newdata=test.lr.cv, type =  
"response")
list_raw_pred.lr.cv[[i]]<-tmp.predict.lr.cv
  }
```

But then the following error pops up:

```
"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,   
xlev = object$xlevels) : Factor 'item_size' has new levels 45+"
```

As the two errors seem to be 'unrelated', I am not sure what exactly the problem is, let alone how to resolve it. "Normal" glm without cross validation is working just fine btw.

Your help is much appreciated.

Best,

Nico

Comment: Could you provide `str(data_known)`?

Comment: Your formula is wrong. You need to refer to variables, not `object$variable`. Not sure if this is what is causing the error, though.

Comment: Provided str(data_known)

Comment: @Nico It's hard to say exactly without having the data, but the first error appears to be caused by `NA` values in column `order_item_id`? Are there any? The 2nd error is caused by the unfortunate fold choice. Folds do not have all the levels for `item_size` since there are so many of them. One possible remedy is to setup folds so they capture all the `item_size` levels.

Comment: @missuse thank you for your reply. naprint(data_known$item_id) gives [1] ""